# Excel counting patterns and cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am wondering if there is a way if:

I have 1000 cells. I would like to see how many times an x is placed in a 7-cell period,

Ie. X is placed in cell 1 and 3. This would count as 1

X is placed in cell 1, 8 and 9. This would count as 2

X is placed in cell 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 170. This would count as 3.

So far I've got,

```
=SUM(IF(COUNTA(M77:N77)=0,0,1),IF(COUNTA(O77:P77)=0,0,1),IF(COUNTA(Q77:R77)=0,0,‌​1))
```

Not sure if VBA would be easier however it would need to be a constant update and would be comparing 10-12 banks of 1000 cells with different 7-cell patterns.

Comment: Your problem description is difficult to follow. It would help if you'd edit it (click the EDIT link below the question), format the conditions (new line for each, for example) and check your punctuation (some periods missing?) Also more information about the structure of the worksheet (banks)?

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize that everything was on one line.

Comment: Mmm, yes, StackOverflow needs two "Enters" to make new lines, OR format with the "bullet" or "numbered" list tool. And for code, format with the CODE tool.

Comment: Why wouldn't an x placed in cells 1 and 3 count twice -- once for cells 1-7 and once for cells 2-8?

Comment: Regardless of how many times a piece of equipment is used it is only billed once. If it is used cell 1, 2, 3 we only bill once. If we use equipment for cells 1 and 8 we would bill twice.

Comment: Are you just checking the cells on one row/column?  Also, from your examples, it looks like you only want to check each cell set that is defined as {1-7}, {8-14}, {15-21}, etc.  Or does John Coleman's comment apply?

Comment: You still need to be precise about what you are counting. Evidently the groups of 7 can't overlap. Can there be gaps between them? For example -- I can cover the set {1,13,16} with two non-overlapping blocks of length 7, but if the blocks have to be {1-7}, {8-14} etc. (as Ric Gaudet suggests) I would need 3 blocks. If the blocks *are* disjoint and gap-free then the fact that 1000 isn't a multiple of 7 seems problematic.

Comment: the actual number of cells is 1001. sets would be {1-7}, {8-14}, {15-21}, etc. I would like to count how many sets are not blank. =SUM(IF(COUNTA(M77:N77)=0,0,1),IF(COUNTA(O77:P77)=0,0,1),IF(COUNTA(Q77:R77)=0,0,1)) was the start however I was hoping for a simpler method than a large sum/if statement

Comment: Why does the COUNTA cover 2 columns and only one row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this user-defined function:  It seems to work, but is not completely tested.  The function will create a circular formula problem if you put the formula in the middle of an x-day span, and it will probably crash and burn if you put in a range with more than 1 row.

I can't figure out any combination of built-in Excel functions to do this sort of progressive counting of a sequence of ranges, but it probably can be done using SUMPRODUCT and other esoteric formulas.  However, having previously spent hours trying to come up with a cute formula that does complex tasks that nobody (including me) will ever understand later, your best bet is to write some code that you can debug and change according to your needs.

But then, eventually, you will have to ask yourself whether using a spreadsheet to do database-like functions is worth the effort.  I assume that you may need to ask yourself that question soon, given the business description you gave :)

```
Public Function CountRangeSpanEntries(span As Integer, rng As Range) As Integer


Dim length As Integer
length = rng.Columns.count

Dim count As Integer
count = 0

Dim rw As Integer
rw = rng.Row

Dim used As Boolean
Dim index As Integer
Dim i As Integer

For index = 1 To length Step span
    For i = index To index + span - 1
        If Cells(rw, i).Value = "x" Then
            used = True
            End If
    Next i
    If used Then
        count = count + 1
        End If
used = False
Next index

CountRangeSpanEntries = count


End Function
```